# What constitutes as a perfect victory?

Tags: divekick

While playing divekick yesterday, I was occasionally treated to a "Perfect" prompt upon besting my opponent. Is there some criteria for achieving a perfect victory, or is this merely a randomly dispensed gag, considering how you always win with full health?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that perfects are as random as they are meaningless, as there appears to be no pattern whatsoever as to how they appear.

Comment: Other bits of the internet seem to agree with you, and I have to say this pretty much lines up with my experience with the game.

Comment: Yes, this is true.  It's intended as a joke - it's funny because *every* round is technically a perfect, but it just arbitrarily picks random ones to call perfect.  Just another bit of fighting game humor.

Answer (score -1):

From watching several games of Divekick, as far as I can tell, you get a "Perfect" when you hit your enemy with your first kick.

Comment: After playing some more divekick yesterday, I am pretty certain this is not the sole condition as I've hit people with my first kick and not gotten a "Perfect" and I even got one when hitting someone on my second kick.